# redirecting dynamic aspx to static url using htaccess

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have dynamic aspx url such as xyz.com/packaging.aspx?page=2 which I want to redirect to xyz.com/casestudy/brochure-design/ (which is php in backend)

I tried below redirect code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=2$
RewriteRule ^/packaging.aspx$ xyz.com/casestudy/archive-packaging-design/ [L,R=302]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=2$
RewriteRule ^/packaging.aspx$ xyz.com/casestudy/archive-packaging-design?/ [L,R=302]
```

It has been redirected to new page but with query string i.e. http://www.xyz.com/casestudy/archive-packaging-design/?page=2

I don't want to have ?page=2 at the end of url as it creates duplicate content issue. I request you all to please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advanced.